# Solving a specific differential equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

I have been trapped in solving the following ODE for a long time. I wonder if it has unique analytical solution
\begin{equation}
[b+c_B(\bar{\beta}^H-\bar{\beta}^L)]\frac{dF(x)}{dx}+c_BF(x)-c_BF(x+\bar{\beta}^H-\bar{\beta}^L-b/c_B)-c_B=0.
\end{equation}

I could try to assume $F(x)$ is linear. But I was wondering if there is a way to prove or disprove the uniqueness of the solution of this ODE? Is there a systematic way to find all the solutions to this equation? Thanks for the comments. Now I know that this is a delay differential equation. In my problem, I have $x\geq b/c_B+\bar{\beta}^L-\bar{\beta}^H$. And in fact, $F(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function in my case.

Comment: It’s not an ODE but a delay differential equation.

Comment: I didn't know this. I am gonna search for it. Thanks!

Comment: Try Fourier/Laplace  transform.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko  I will try to read some reference about that. I haven't done any Fourier stuff before, though I've heard about it many times... Do you think for a problem like this, first-order delay differential equation, is promising to solve analytically?

Comment: [以前在学习解方程的时候，延迟的这种好像可以配成一种特别的函数，等会回去给你查一下](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=以前在学习解方程的时候，延迟的这种好像可以配成一种特别的函数，等会回去给你查一下)

Comment: please use the answer box only for an answer to the question; this is a comment, not an answer. (also, writing in English is strongly recommended on this site, to ensure that everyone can participate in the discussion)

Comment: @user140272 The whole point of this site is that  questions, answers and comments   are  accessible  to  any person,  such as  yourself,   who  understands  English.

Comment: @user140272  I hope to discuss with you about this in detail. Please check my profile and contact me by email. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To continue Liviu Nicolaescu's simplification: put $F(x):=f(x/B)$ so the equation writes
$$f'(x)+f(x)-f(x+1)+1=0.$$
A particular solution of it is simply $f(x):=x^2$, so we are left with the homogeneous equation 
$$u'(x)+u(x)-u(x+1)=0.$$
If we put $u(x)=v(x)e^{-x}$ this becomes the (well-known)
$$v'(x)=\lambda v(x+1)$$
with $\lambda=1/e$.

Comment: A solution of the homogeneous equation is $u(x)=ax+b$, or  $v(x)=(ax+b)e^x$, btw.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just guess $u(x)=ax+b$ and I plug it into my DDE and solve for the value of $a$.  Here, can I claim the unique solution to this DDE has to have the form $u(x)=ax+b+x^2$? I am a little bit lost in the part where you say "If we put $u(x)=v(x)e^{-x}$, this becomes...". This seems to suggest that $u(x)=v(x)e^{-x}$ is the only way to solve this homogenous equation. Is this related to characteristic functions?

Comment: Could you please provide some references on how to solve $v'(x)=\lambda v(x+1)$, to get $v(x)=(ax+b)e^x$? I can verify that it is correct, but how to solve this delay differential equation in a systematic way and is the uniqueness guaranteed? Thanks!

Comment: @FTXX: One general approach to analyse delay differential equations in a systematic way (and to obtain uniqueness) is to use the theory of $C_0$-semigroups; see for instance Sections II.3.29 and VI.6 in "Engel, Nagel: One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations (2000)", or the entire monograph "Bátkai, Piazzera: Semigroups for Delay Equations (2005)".

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but a suggestion.   There is a lot of "noise" in your equation.    You can simplify it a bit.  Set 
$$
A:= b+c_B(\bar{\beta}^H-\bar{\beta}^L),\;\;c:=c_B.
$$
Then your equation reads
$$
AF'(x)+cF(x)-cF(x+A/c)-c=0,
$$
or
$$
BF'(x)+F(x)-F(x+B)+1=0,\;\;B=A/c.
$$
This is a linear autonomous delay equation. As some commented, try Fourier transform. Alternatively, have a look at Chapter VII  in the book *Ordinary and Delay Differential Equations*, by R.D. Driver.